# How do I prepend a string or character to a number of file names in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, rename

I have a long list of files which I can see in Windows Explorer.  I want to prepend a dash to the front of each file instead of clicking on each file individually and prepending the "-"

*original*:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

*new*:

```
-file1
-file2
-file3
```

Any suggestions that are easy to execute?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What research have you done so far? :)

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell is the answer!

Hold Shift and right-click in open space in the Explorer window where you can see your files and select "**Open PowerShell window here**":
[image: Opening a PowerShell window from Windows Explorer]
In the resulting window use the following statement:

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {"-" + $_.name}
```

What's happening is the `ls` command is passing its output (list of files in that directory) to the `Rename-Item` command, where the name structure is specified in the braces `{}`. In PowerShell `$_` is a placeholder for whatever object is currently being processed, in this case each file. In this way we can quickly and easily prepend any string to the filename.

Here's PowerShell in action:
[image: Running the rename statement]

A word of ***caution*** - this command will make this change to **all** files contained in this folder. If you only want to make this change to a subset of files, I would suggest (A) moving the files into their own folder before doing this or (B) filtering the list of files further in PowerShell, explained below:

Renaming Text files only, and excluding the RTF document:
[image: Renaming *.txt files only]
This is the statement:

```
ls *.* -Include *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {"-" + $_.name}
```

The syntax is slightly different - we need to specify the Path and all viable files `*.*` which we then filter down using `-Include *.txt`. From there the process is the same.

This would also work, and I prefer it actually:

```
ls *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {"-" + $_.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not sure there is a simple way to do this from File Explorer itself.

Instead, I might suggest using a program called [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php). It's free for personal, non-commercial use and while its interface may look slightly daunting, it's relatively easy to use in most cases.

If you wish to give it a try, please follow these steps:

1. [Download and install Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Downloads/BRU_setup.exe). If you only need to use it temporarily (e.g. just for this one task) or cannot install software, there is a [portable "No Installer" version](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Downloads/BRU_NoInstall.zip) as well.
2. Open the program and navigate to the folder containing your files. You can either type a direct path (after which, you would press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or you can use the folder tree in the upper left to navigate your through your folders:

   [image: Bulk Rename Utility Screenshot - Navigation]
3. In middle-right portion of the Bulk Rename Utility window, look for the option marked `Add (7)` and type a `-` in the `Prefix` field:

   [image: Bulk Rename Utility Screenshot - Add (7) Option Version 2]
4. Towards the bottom left, find the option marked `Filters (12)` and *uncheck* the `Folders` checkbox item:

   [image: Bulk Rename Utility Screenshot - Filters (12) Option]

   Once you do this, any folders in the directory will no longer be displayed in the main file window:

   [image: Bulk Rename Utility - Hidden Folders]
5. From the main menu bar, select *Actions → Select All* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>). All the currently visible files in the working directory should be highlighted in blue, with a preview of the new file names appearing in green under the `New Name` column:

   [image]
6. Assuming you are happy with the `New Name` results, press the large *Rename* button in the lower right. Press *OK* in the warning dialog to confirm you wish to rename the files.

---

*If you make an option mistake you can't correct (before the rename is applied), you can select Actions → Reset All Naming Criteria (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) to return all the options to their default states.*

---

Comment: This sounds like a product pitch not an answer. As in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791264/how-to-replace-all-spaces-by-underscores-in-all-file-names-of-a-folder/20791817) from StackOverflow for one. It can also be done using Excel, which most people have, [link](https://benholland.me/tutorials/2011/11/11/rename-multiple-files-using-excel-in-windows.html)

Comment: In some ways, using a batch command line solution is closer to the spirit of "Using Windows 10 File Explorer" in the sense that it's a native Windows solution. On the other hand, "Using Windows 10 File Explorer" can also mean they might want a GUI solution. Hence the answer given.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple...   Open a DOS prompt and navigate to the directory where these files are located.

Type     REN * -*       and press enter

Be careful, this will add a "-" to the beginning of every file in the directory.